# Need help understanding slow DSL connection

Tags: modem, adsl

I got a strange problem with my DSL connection.

When I run a speed test I consistently get an internet speed of **5Mbit/s** downstream. I have ran the test at different times and weekdays but it is always the same (and I really mean the same +/-1%).

The plan I got with my ISP is up to 28Mbit/s.

When I look into the modem it says it is connection using ASDL2+ with a bitrate of 20.5Mbit/s. (I got approx 2km to the station)

The SNR is ok (don't remember the exact figure) and if I use the modem's BER-test it tells me 0 bit errors over 60 seconds and 20Mbit/s (it actually says the number of bits transmitted but if I divide it by 60 I get approx 20Mbit)

All this together tells me the station is communicating with my modem at 20Mbit/s.

**Is this correct?**

If so it means that the 5Mbit/s bottleneck is not between the station and the modem.

My ISP does not listen to this and:

- They asked me to try with another modem which I did without any difference
  (bought a new modem which I could return)
- They asked me to try with different splitter and cable which didn't make any difference.
- They asked me to try different ports on the modem with no difference
  (I can transfer files between computers on my lan at 100Mbit/s)

I also did some tests myself and found a strange thing.

I turned of ASDL2+ and used G.bis (or whatever it is called).
The modem connected to the station with 13Mbit/s and still 0 bit errors.
The strange thing is that the speed test now shows **11Mbit/s** to internet.

**Can anyone explain this?**

The ISP wants to send a technician to my house but say that I have to pay for him if the problem is in my end.

In all cases the uplink is approx 1Mbit/s
The modem is a 3 year old Dlink (but I got exact same numbers with a brand new TPlink)
Only one computer was connected to the modem with a cable during the tests (have tried with different computers and also wireless)

**What should I do?**

Comment: `The ISP wants to send a technician to my house but say that I have to pay for him if the problem is in my end.` So pay it! Usually they only charge if you have done something stupid! The fact that you've gone into this detail and level shows you have a high understanding, I really don't think you'd get charged (assuming your router is plugged into the main point in the house (and you take off the plastic housing and plug direct inside))